# Presenting a view controller shows navigation controller under it

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have tab bar controller. From one of the tabs I present a controller like so:

```
present(vc1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now this view controller covers the the tab bar controller. From this controller I now want to present another controller. Again I use

```
present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I also have  `self.definesPresentationContext = true` set in vc1.

This controller is not full screen size (it's a dialogue box) and it doesn't show vc1 underneath. Instead it shows the tab bar controller. When I dismiss it vc1 is shown again. What am I doing wrong here? I want to present from v1 and show vc1 underneath not the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
vc2.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
vc2.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

before `present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)`